# Temperature Measurement Of Interstellar Matter

Tags: astrophysics

Have read many articles about the temperature of interstellar gas/dust/plasma.  Recently, Voyage2 departed the heliosphere.  According to a paper this article below, "In one of the papers, the researchers suggest that the interstellar medium near the heliopause — the boundary at the edge of the heliosphere — is hotter than expected, with a temperature of around 30,000–50,000°K"

How are they measuring such a hot, but yet, extremely diffuse gas?  What is the tech behind the instrument?

Thank you so much for your time.

https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-7647729/NASAs-Voyager-2-space-probe-sends-discoveries-interstellar-space.html

Answer (score 1):

In section 4 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.00676.pdf), the autors claim that "[...] the temperature in the VLISM is not directly measured"; from what I understood, they measure a total effetctive pressure with a nominal value of $P_{Total} = 267 \pm 55$ fPa. The instrument that measures this pressure is the [Plasma Science (PLS)](https://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/mission/spacecraft/instruments/pls/). From this, they use some equation of state to determine a temperature of $ T_{VLISM} = 20,000$ K. Notice that this temperature is simply a measure of the kinetic energy of the particles composing the plasma: you wouldn't necessarily experience such hot temperatures if transported there.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.

Comment: If this helps and you don't mind, please accept/upvote this answer